# Make Alexa Skill Slot accept any word user says

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I was wandering if there is a way to make custom Alexa Skill slot accept any word user can say.
I need it to detect a name of a user device. User can name his device how he wants (person name, thing name, singer name and so on...) so there isn't a default slot can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AMAZON.SearchQuery](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#searchquery) for that case. Once upon a time there was [AMAZON.Literal](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/literal-slot-type-reference.html), but it's depricated now.